# Is extrude face along normal that can be done in edit mode also possible in geometry node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

I would like to create the right side of the attached image using a geometry node.
However, the geometry node's extrude mesh must be executed by selecting one of the three types: "face", "edge", and "vertical", so the extrude mesh shown on the right
I think expressing the mesh is difficult.
This is my first post, but I would be happy if someone could show me the node tree.
I would also be happy if you could tell me how to implicitly calculate extrude face along normal.

Comment: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ *blender** `code`

Comment: you can extrude the way you indicate using geometry nodes. but to do that some rules about selecting the initial faces are needed. do you have such rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do you mean like this?

[image]

Just use selection for only one face, e.g. by index (or normal or whatever)

and this is how you can extrude along normal:

[image]

and this is a nodetree example how you can select via direction:

[image]

> Note: Dot product is near 1 or 1 if the direction of two vector are the
> same or nearly the same.

Comment: I guess since the question asks for getting the result on the right side of the screenshot, first of all I would turn off _Individual_ in the _Extrude Mesh_. Apart from that the setup where you extrude the single face would do what is expected (at least if he does not want the "Even Thickness" option of the original tool). The _Normal_ node is not even necessary, at least in my Blender it uses the normal by default. Now he only needs a good way of selecting the desired faces.